# Converting a Postgres query to Rails ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to write the following query in Rail's ActiveRecord format? I've tried a billion different ways with arel but can't get the same results.

```
SELECT topic_id, count(*) as total
FROM questions_topics
WHERE question_id IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM questions
  WHERE user_id = 1000
  UNION ALL
  SELECT questions.id
  FROM questions JOIN answers ON (questions.id = answers.question_id)
  WHERE answers.user_id = 1000
)
GROUP BY topic_id
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Comment: Do you have relevant models like QuestionTopic and others?

Comment: I'd start by converting it to EXISTS (...) OR EXISTS (...) form, which will probably be more efficient than a UNION.

Comment: Maybe this talk will help you understand Arel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShPAxNcLm3o It explains how to convert any SQL query to Arel AST

Comment: Why do you want to convert it? One piece of SQL will probably be a lot clearer than an incomprehensible mess of Arel calls.

Comment: @muistooshort Since using Arel could allow rails to utilize lazy loading. I might be incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this should work. Not exactly the same thing but should give same results.

```
QuestionTopic.where(
  "question_id IN (?) OR question_id IN (?)",
  Question.where(user_id: 1000).select(:id),
  Answer.where(user_id: 1000).select(:question_id)
).group('topic_id')
 .order('total desc')
 .select('topic_id, count(*) as total')
```

Comment: Exactly looking for this. Thank you