# OR condition in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Try makes the following query:

```
title = "%#{params[:title]}%"
group = params[:group]

@foods = Food.order('visits_count DESC').where("title ILIKE ? OR group ILIKE ?", title, group).decorate
```

and in return I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "group"
LINE 1: ..."foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE (title ILIKE '%%' OR group ILIK...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE (title ILIKE '%%' OR group ILIKE '') ORDER BY visits_count DESC):
```

Any ideas?

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23700169/converting-a-postgres-query-to-rails-activerecord?rq=1

Comment: Is `group` a SQL keyword? Should that be ``group``, with back-ticks?

Comment: I already tried but I get the same error: `ActionView::Template::Error (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "group"
LINE 1: ... "foods".* FROM "foods" WHERE (title IN ('%%') OR group IN (...`

Comment: @Phlip Are you right, how can you solve it without going backwards on the db, losing all that data? Thanks!

Comment: This is why `Arel` should be used more often.

`where(Food.arel_table[:title].matches(title).or(Food.arel_table[:group].matches(group)))` looks uglier, but you are way less likely to get into trouble like this :)

Comment: You could try [where_chain](https://github.com/marcinruszkiewicz/where_chain) `Food.where.like(title: title).or(Food.where.like(group: group))`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
"group"
```

with double-quotes.

Comment: I think the best thing is to renounce the column, in this way the serious changes and I would not lose the data, thank you very much!

Comment: I think you mean "rename" the column.

Comment: That won't work with PostgreSQL. Backtick quoting is a MySQL-ism, standard SQL and PostgreSQL use double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is PostgreSQL, you need to quote identifiers using double quotes when case sensitivity is an issue or you're using a keyword as an identifier:

```
...where('title ILIKE ? OR "group" ILIKE ?', title, group)...
```

You'd be better off not using a keyword as a column IMO so that you don't have to worry about this sort of thing. I'd go with he quoting for now and then rename the column as soon as possible but that's just me.

While I'm here, you might want to leave out those checks when they don't make sense. This part of your query:

```
title ILIKE '%%'
```

will always match when `title` is not null so you might want to use an explicit `not null` check or leave it out entirely when there is no `title`. Similarly for `"group" ILIKE ''` which only matches when `"group"` is empty.

Comment: You already change the name of the column, thank you very much!